# CreateRemoteThread() succeeds yet doesn't do anything

Tags: c++, winapi, dll-injection

I'm trying to inject dll (found in `dll_path[]` and it's **correct** path) into target process using `CreateRemoteThread()`. Unfortunately completely nothing happens (expected result is `MessageBox()` call from `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` resulting in window pop up). 
It works **properly** when used with remote injector.

You can treat every `what()` call as `GetLastError()` and `assert(0)`. It is guaranteed that variable `PID` will contain correct process id (I tested it many times). Also **none** of the function calls you see in code below fails. Funny thing is that it worked well until I rewrote it from C to more C++-like code which you can see below. I compiled code below and dll code without any warnings. I wonder where do I made mistake. Here's my code:

```
int main() {

    const WCHAR dll_path[] = L"C:\\myDLL.dll";

    const std::wstring process_name = L"target.exe";

    const DWORD PID = get_PID(process_name);

    if (!PID)
        what();

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID);
    if (!process)
        what();

    FARPROC lib = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if (!lib)
        what();

    LPVOID base = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(process, 0, wcslen(dll_path), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!base)
        what();

    BOOL good = WriteProcessMemory(process, base, dll_path, wcslen(dll_path), 0);
    if (!good)
        what();

    HANDLE thread = CreateRemoteThread(process, 0, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(lib), base, 0, 0);
    if (!thread)
        what();    

    if (thread) {
        std::cout << "Remote thread successfully created." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "process ID = " << PID << std::endl;
    }

#if 1
    CloseHandle(thread);
    CloseHandle(process);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `LPVOID base = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(process, 0, wcslen(dll_path), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);` -- what about allocating memory for the string's null terminator? And subsequently writing it as well!

Answer (score 6):

As @adelphus said, you are using `LoadLibraryA()` when you should be using `LoadLibraryW()` instead.

More importantly, you are not allocating enough memory in the remote process to hold your **wide** DLL path string.  `VirtualAllocEx()` and `WriteProcessMemory()` operate on bytes, not on characters. And you need to make sure that you allocate *AND* copy the string's null terminator as well.  So you need to use `(wcslen(dll_path) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR)`, or you can use `sizeof(dll_path)` since it is a static array.

Now, with that said, since the remote thread procedure is `LoadLibrary()` itself, the thread's exit code will be the return value of `LoadLibrary()`.  If `CreateRemoteThread()` is successful, you can call `WaitForSingleObject()` to wait for the thread to terminate, and then call `GetExitCodeThread()` to get `LoadLibrary()`'s return value.  If it is 0, `LoadLibrary()` failed, even though the thread itself succeeded.

```
int main() {

    const WCHAR dll_path[] = L"C:\\myDLL.dll";    
    const int dll_path_size = (wcslen(dll_path) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR); // or sizeof(dll_path);

    const std::wstring process_name = L"target.exe";

    const DWORD PID = get_PID(process_name);    
    if (!PID)
        what();

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, PID);
    if (!process)
        what();

    FARPROC lib = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");
    if (!lib)
        what();

    LPVOID base = VirtualAllocEx(process, 0, dll_path_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!base)
        what();

    BOOL good = WriteProcessMemory(process, base, dll_path, dll_path_size, 0);
    if (!good)
        what();

    HANDLE thread = CreateRemoteThread(process, 0, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(lib), base, 0, 0);
    if (!thread)
        what();    

    std::cout << "Remote thread successfully created." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "process ID = " << PID << std::endl;

    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);

    DWORD exitCode = 0;
    GetExitCodeThread(thread, &exitCode);

    if (exitCode != 0)
        std::cout << "DLL loaded successfully." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "DLL load failed." << std::endl;

    #if 1
    CloseHandle(thread);
    CloseHandle(process);
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, you will not be able to discover why `LoadLibrary()` failed, unless you change your remote thread logic to inject an entire function that calls `LoadLibrary()` and `GetLastError()` together and then returns the value from `GetLastError()`.  The value from `GetLastError()` is stored in thread-local storage.  One thread cannot read another thread's error code (unless you dig down into the bowls of the OS and read the remote thread's TIB structure directly).

And lastly, be sure to take into account whether the target process is 32bit or 64bit.  You cannot inject a 32bit DLL into a 64bit process, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made changes that you mentioned and library loaded properly and it worked. Thank you

Comment: @MichałKryszak: *"And lastly, be sure to take into account whether the target process is 32bit or 64bit. You cannot inject a 32bit DLL into a 64bit process, and vice versa."* - Did you account for that as well?

Comment: @MichałKryszak if this answer solved your problem you should make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `LoadLibraryA` with a pointer that points to a widechar string. You probably meant `LoadLibraryW`?

Comment: It still doesn't do anything.